# Plotting the solution of a Chini differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear

In DIFFERENTIAL EQUATION  SOLVING WITH DSOLVE by D. Kapadia, there is a Chini differential equation :

```
sol = DSolve[x'[t] == 5 x[t]^4 + 3 x[t]^(-4/3), x[t], t]
```

The answer implies RootSum. The question is how to use and plot the solution. I have tried

```
Plot[x[t] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 2}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

which doesn't works and used Evaluate and/or Normal and/or ToRadical@Normal both on x[t] and on sol. But nothing works. Moreover, this case is not documented in the documentation "Plotting the Solution".

Need help; Thanks

Comment: Hold up… if you try `N[x[10] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 2}]`, what do you get?

Comment: If I do that I have that the sol is neither a list of replacement rule...

Comment: …and now you know why it doesn't work within `Plot[]`.

Comment: Ok but that does not resolve my problem. I allready have found this but I do not know how to proceed. It's strange to find a solution in a manual of how to and not to be able to apply it.

Comment: I don't have *Mathematica* on hand at the moment. Can you paste in the result `sol` in `InputForm`?

Comment: You mean this Solve[-45 RootSum[-45 + 3^(1/4) 5^(3/4) #1 - 45 #1^4 &, 
    Log[-#1 + (5/3)^(1/4) (t^(4/3))^(1/4) x[t]]/(
     3^(1/4) 5^(3/4) - 180 #1^3) &] == 
  C[1] + (3^(3/4) 5^(1/4) t Log[t])/(t^(4/3))^(3/4), x[t]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative approach is to solve for `t[x]` instead of `x[t]`.

```
t[x] /. First@DSolve[t'[x] == 1/(5 x^4 + 3 x^(-4/3)), t[x], x] /. C[1] -> 0;
ParametricPlot[{Chop@%, x}, {x, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {t + C[1], x}, 
    AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Because the ODE determines `t[x]` only up to an arbitrary constant, the curve above can be shifted by an arbitrary amount to the left or right.

Comment: I wonder why Chop@% work and not Chop@t

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki  `t` actually is not defined by my two lines of code.  To define it, use `t = s[x] /. First@DSolve[s'[x] == 1/(5 x^4 + 3 x^(-4/3)), s[x], x] /. C[1] -> 0; ParametricPlot[{Chop@t, x}, {x, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"t+C[1]", x}, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio]`.  Note that I use `s[x]` as the dummy variable in the first equation here to avoid possible issues.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this:

```
sol = DSolve[x'[t] == 5 x[t]^4 + 3 x[t]^(-4/3), x[t], t]
eq = sol[[1, 1, 2, 0, 1]][x] == (sol[[1, 1, 2, 1]] /. C[1] -> 2)
ContourPlot[sol[[1, 1, 2, 0, 1]][x] == (sol[[1, 1, 2, 1]] /. C[1] -> 2),
{t, -3, 3}, {x, -3, 3}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AxesLabel -> {t, x[t]}]
```

[image]

**EDITED:**

If You exectue this code:

```
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{Solve}, Unprotect[Solve];
 Solve[x___] := 
 Block[{$guard = True}, Print["Solve called : ", HoldForm[Solve[x]]];
 Solve[x]] /; ! TrueQ[$guard];
 DSolve[{x'[t] == 5 x[t]^4 + 3 x[t]^(-4/3)}, x[t], t]];
```

[image]

You can see `DSolve` cant find solution.Then solution of `Solve` convert to `InverseFuntion`.
I'm only extract this solution using [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html?q=Part) function.

Comment: Thank you Mariusz it works perfectly even if I do not understand the philosophy behind. The mainchange is from x to x[t], in Dsolve and it change all.

Comment: I,m only using `Part` function.That all.